# How to open a file from terminal in unity

Tags: unity, command-line

What would the equivalent of 'gnome-open foo.pdf' be in unity? Thanks!

Comment: This very same question was asked earlier today even ;)

Comment: Ah, I guess google hasn't picked it up yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can open any file with its default application with the command `xdg-open`

Answer (score 0):

The program to open PDF file in gnome is `evince`. 
Just run this :

```
evince foo.pdf
```